I'm wondering why my usercontrol isn't working properly
I want use RangeSlider, without extendedToolkit package.
So I made a RangeSlider and start Test.
NormalSlider works well without Bindingmode.Twoway,So I did not add twoway to any bindings.
Test Result
When I dragging normalSlider, This Value is changed.

normalSlider.Value
TTTTT.Value
rangeSlider.LowValue

When I dragging rangeSlider, This Value is changed.

rangeSlider.LowValue

And I dragging normalSlider again, This Value is changed;

normalSlider.Value
TTTTT.Value

Normal Action that I want:
When I dragging normalSlider, This Value should changed.

normalSlider.Value
TTTTT.Value
rangeSlider.LowValue

When I dragging rangeSlider, This Value should changed.

normalSlider.Value
TTTTT.Value
rangeSlider.LowValue

<Window Name="window" x:Class="CommonTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommonTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid Background="Gray" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=window}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Slider Name="normalSlider" Value="{Binding TTTTTT.LowValue}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Binding Element"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,ElementName=normalSlider}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Binding TTTTTT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TTTTTT.LowValue}"/>
            <local:RangeSlider Name="rangeSlider" ValueChanged="rangeSlider_ValueChanged"  IsRangeVisiable="True"  LowValue="{Binding TTTTTT.LowValue}" HighValue="{Binding TTTTTT.HighValue}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Binding Element"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowValue,ElementName=rangeSlider}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Binding TTTTTT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TTTTTT.LowValue}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


And Behind Code Here
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));


        private MyTestValues tTTTTT;

        public MyTestValues TTTTTT { get => tTTTTT; set => Set(ref tTTTTT, value); }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            TTTTTT = new MyTestValues { HighValue = 100, LowValue = 0 };
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rangeSlider_ValueChanged(SliderValueType arg1, double arg2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Range Slider Value is Changed");
        }
    }

    public class MyTestValues : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));




        private double lowValue;
        private double highValue;


        public double LowValue { get => lowValue; set => Set(ref lowValue, value); }
        public double HighValue { get => highValue; set => Set(ref highValue, value); }
    }

This is my RangeSlider Code
<UserControl Name="userControl" x:Class="Common.Control.RangeSlider"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cvt="clr-namespace:Common.Control.Converters"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Common.Control"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <cvt:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="cvtBoolToVisibility"/>
            <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Border Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CornerRadius="10"/>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid PreviewMouseDown="rangeSliderArea_PreviewMouseDown" Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=userControl}">
        <Border Name="backGroundArea" Height="5"/>
        <Border Name="rangeArea" Height="5" Background="White" Visibility="{Binding IsRangeVisiable,Converter={StaticResource cvtBoolToVisibility}}"/>
        <Grid Name="rangeSliderArea">
            <Thumb Name="lowThumb" Thumb.DragStarted="DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="DragCompleted" Thumb.DragDelta="DragDelta">
                <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding LowPosX}"/>
                </Thumb.RenderTransform>
            </Thumb>

            <Thumb Name="highThumb" Thumb.DragStarted="DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="DragCompleted" Thumb.DragDelta="DragDelta">
                <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding HighPosX}"/>
                </Thumb.RenderTransform>
            </Thumb>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

namespace Common.Control
{
    public enum SliderValueType
    {
        Low,
        High
    }
    public partial class RangeSlider : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region DP
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRangeVisiableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsRangeVisiable", typeof(bool), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(100.0, MaximumPropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, MinimumPropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LowValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LowValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, LowValuePropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, HighValuePropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(RangeSlider), new PropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal, OrientationPropertyChanged));
        public bool IsReadOnly { get => (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); set => SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
        public bool IsRangeVisiable { get => (bool)GetValue(IsRangeVisiableProperty); set => SetValue(IsRangeVisiableProperty, value); }
        public double Maximum { get => (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); set => SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        public double Minimum { get => (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); set => SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        public double LowValue { get => (double)GetValue(LowValueProperty); set => SetValue(LowValueProperty, value); }
        public double HighValue { get => (double)GetValue(HighValueProperty); set => SetValue(HighValueProperty, value); }
        public Orientation Orientation { get => (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); set => SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
        private static void MaximumPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as RangeSlider;
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.Low);
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.High);
        }
        private static void MinimumPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as RangeSlider;
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.Low);
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.High);
        }
        private static void LowValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as RangeSlider;
            sender.CheckInRange(SliderValueType.Low);
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.Low);
            sender.ValueChanged?.Invoke(SliderValueType.Low, sender.LowValue);
        }
        private static void HighValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as RangeSlider;
            sender.CheckInRange(SliderValueType.High);
            sender.UpdateView(SliderValueType.High);
            sender.ValueChanged?.Invoke(SliderValueType.High, sender.HighValue);
        }
        private static void OrientationPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sender = d as RangeSlider;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Variables
        private double lowPosX;
        private double highPosX;
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public event Action<SliderValueType, double> ValueChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }



        private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        private double Range_value => Maximum - Minimum;
        private double SliderWidth_Pixel => rangeSliderArea.ActualWidth - lowThumb.Width;
        private double ValuePerPixel => SliderWidth_Pixel / Range_value;

        public double LowPosX { get => lowPosX; set => Set(ref lowPosX, value); }
        public double HighPosX { get => highPosX; set => Set(ref highPosX, value); }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public RangeSlider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += RangeSlider_Loaded;
            SizeChanged += RangeSlider_SizeChanged;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Finalizer
        ~RangeSlider()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Functions
        private void UpdateView(SliderValueType valueType)
        {
            switch (valueType)
            {
                case SliderValueType.Low:
                    if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                    {
                        var distanceFromLeft_pixel = (LowValue - Minimum) * ValuePerPixel;
                        var distanceHighLow = (HighValue - LowValue) * ValuePerPixel;
                        rangeArea.Margin = new Thickness(distanceFromLeft_pixel, 0, SliderWidth_Pixel - distanceFromLeft_pixel - distanceHighLow, 0);
                        LowPosX = distanceFromLeft_pixel;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    break;
                case SliderValueType.High:
                    if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                    {
                        var distanceFromLeft_pixel = (HighValue - Minimum) * ValuePerPixel;
                        var distanceHighLow = (HighValue - LowValue) * ValuePerPixel;
                        rangeArea.Margin = new Thickness(distanceFromLeft_pixel - distanceHighLow, 0, SliderWidth_Pixel - distanceFromLeft_pixel, 0);
                        HighPosX = distanceFromLeft_pixel;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void CheckInRange(SliderValueType sliderValue)
        {
            switch (sliderValue)
            {
                case SliderValueType.Low:
                    if (LowValue > HighValue) LowValue = HighValue;
                    if (LowValue < Minimum) LowValue = Minimum;
                    break;
                case SliderValueType.High:
                    if (HighValue < LowValue) HighValue = LowValue;
                    if (HighValue > Maximum) HighValue = Maximum;
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void MoveBlockTo(Point point, SliderValueType block)
        {
            double position;
            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                position = point.X;
            }
            else
            {
                position = point.Y;
            }

            var value = Math.Min(Maximum, Minimum + (position / SliderWidth_Pixel) * (Maximum - Minimum));
            if (block == SliderValueType.Low)
            {
                LowValue = value;
            }
            else if (block == SliderValueType.High)
            {
                HighValue = value;
            }
        }
        #region Event_Functions
        private void RangeSlider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateView(SliderValueType.Low);
            UpdateView(SliderValueType.High);
        }
        private void RangeSlider_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateView(SliderValueType.Low);
            UpdateView(SliderValueType.High);
        }


        private void rangeSliderArea_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsReadOnly)
            {
                if ((lowThumb != null && lowThumb.IsMouseOver) || (highThumb != null && highThumb.IsMouseOver))
                    return;

                var point = e.GetPosition(rangeSliderArea);
                if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                {
                    MoveBlockTo(point, SliderValueType.Low);
                }
                else if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
                {
                    MoveBlockTo(point, SliderValueType.High);
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        private void DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsReadOnly && e.OriginalSource is Thumb thumb && rangeSliderArea != null)
            {
                double changedValue = 0.0;
                if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                {
                    var currentChange_PixelWidth = e.HorizontalChange;
                    changedValue = currentChange_PixelWidth / ValuePerPixel;
                }
                if (thumb == lowThumb)
                {
                    LowValue += changedValue;
                }
                else if (thumb == highThumb)
                {
                    HighValue += changedValue;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}


Are you aware of why default Slider's Value which inherits RangeBase.Value dependency property works in TwoWay mode without explicitly setting so in xaml? It is because that dependency property is defined specifying FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault. See the source.
If you want to make your LowValue dependency property work without explicitly setting TwoWay in xaml, you will need to define it in the same way as shown below.
public static readonly DependencyProperty LowValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "LowValue",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(RangeSlider),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, LowValuePropertyChanged));

As a side note, for data binding of a view element which inherits DependencyObject, dependency property is more appropriate than adding INotifyPropertyChanged.

Thanks for your help.
I didn't know that MS Source Code is opened.
My problem is solved. Thank you again.
